# unexpected side effect vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a newbie in `vue.js`. I have a problem with side effect in computed property. I'm not sure why i'm getting an unexpected side effect in computer property error with the code below. ESlint shows me this error in console. I found what does it mean, but I dont have any idea how to change. Any ideas?

```
export default {
    name: "Repaid",
    components: {
    VueSlideBar
    },
    data() {
    return {
      response: {},
       slider: {
       lineHeight: 8,
       value: 2000,
       data: []
      },
     days: {},
     monthCounts: [5],
     currentMonthCount: 5,
     isLoading: false,
     errorMessage: "",
     validationError: ""
   };
   },
     computed: {
       finalPrice() {
       const index = this.monthCounts.indexOf(this.currentMonthCount); 
       this.days = Object.keys(this.response.prices)[index]; =>this is my side effect
        const payment = this.response.prices[this.days] 
        [this.slider.value].schedule[0].amount;
   }
 },
```

I read that i should add slide() to my variable that.days, to mutate the original object. Or maybe I should carry them to the methodes.

**EDIT**

I carried all my calculations to methods and trigger a function in `computed property`.
Now it looks like this:

```
 methods: {
     showPeriod() {
       const index = this.monthCounts.indexOf(this.currentMonthCount); 
       this.days = Object.keys(this.response.prices)[index];
       const payment = this.response.prices[this.days][this.slider.value]
        .schedule[0].amount;
       return "R$ " + payment;
     },
   }
 computed: {
    finalPrice() {
      if (!this.response.prices || this.monthCounts === []) {
        return "";
      }
     return this.showPeriod();
  }
},
```

Comment: If you're not using `days` anywhere else in the component, you could make it a local variable in the computed method. And if you are using it somewhere else, you could make it a computed property.

Comment: Yes, I am using, but eslint show this message like en error not warrning, and I can not push the code to gitLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from "eslint-plugin-vue" and the link for that rule is below,

https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.html

Either you override this rule in your eslint rules file or you can simply turn off the eslint for this specific line like below

```
this.days = Object.keys(this.response.prices)[index]; // eslint-disable-line
```

-- 
One more thing (Not related to your question) is that you need to return some value in computed.